# Return order number of date range by group

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet where each row is an Account Name and date they created tickets. I'm trying to add a column that calculates the order number of that ticket for that Account relative to the date created.

Example:

| Account Name | Date Created | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01-03 | 2 |
| B | 2022-01-10 | 2 |
| A | 2022-01-07 | 3 |
| A | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| A | 2022-01-15 | 4 |
| B | 2022-01-07 | 1 |
| B | 2022-01-20 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B, LAMBDA (a,b,IF(a="","",RANK(b,FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=a),-1))))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!